# Sharing AWS KMS keys across accounts using KMS grants

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-kms

I want to share an encrypted snapshot with another account, and I came across the following AWS article
[Share an Amazon EBS snapshot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-modifying-snapshot-permissions.html#share-kms-key).
The article explains:

> When you share an encrypted snapshot, you must also share the customer managed key used to encrypt the snapshot.

To share the KMS key, I have to edit the key policy, and add the following statement:

```
{
  "Sid": "Allow attachment of persistent resources", 
  "Effect": "Allow", 
  "Principal": {
    "AWS": ["arn:aws:iam::111122223333:user/KeyUser", "arn:aws:iam::444455556666:root"]
  },
  "Action": ["kms:CreateGrant", "kms:ListGrants", "kms:RevokeGrant"],
  "Resource": "*",
  "Condition": {
    "Bool": {
      "kms:GrantIsForAWSResource": true
    }
  }
}
```

I want to achieve the same effect by using KMS grants, but I didn't find the equivalent way to do it.

I tried to use [CreateGrant API](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.26.83/reference/services/kms/client/create_grant.html) with the actions list above ("CreateGrant", "ListGrants", "RevokeGrant"), but it doesn't support the "ListGrants" and "RevokeGrant" operations.
When I tried running it only with the "CreateGrant" operation, I got an error that passing this action only is not valid.